# Get all strings separated by newlines in text area

Tags: regex

Hi I'll like to get strings that are separated by a newline from a text area in javascript.

If the following is entered in a text area

```
1
2
3
4
```

I'll like to get a regex match of

```
["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

I've tried `/\n?(.*)/g` and a few other variations but I wasn't able to get the combination that I wanted. Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `split()`

```
var arrayOfLines = $('textarea').val().split('\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to try this one

```
/^.*?$/g
```

It selects the whole line from the beginning (`^`) to the end (`$`).
Your's selects the newlines, which is a good approach, but not optimal in this place.

Comment: I wanted to break the strings between newlines up into an array, which was why I was toying with the regex with newlines.

Comment: @ZellLiew Yep that does exactly that. You call some method `getMatches` or `getAllMatches` after you executed the regex. It will return all matched *whole lines* as an array or a list.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to what I'm searching for.

```
var matches = $('textarea').val().split('\n');
```

This worked and I got the result that I wanted.

Comment: I didn't realize you answered your own question when I was typing the answer =)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using JavaScript or Perl?

Try this:

```
/^[^\n]+$/mg
```